# Google Charts: get rid of line offset?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm using the Google Visualization API for my charts but I can't figure out how to format the line chart.

My chart looks something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pw7Dz/

How do I make the curve start right next to the axis, as opposed it having an offset like it does now?

Comment: `right next to the axis` - which one axis? Do you mean you want them to start from the vertical axis (the left side)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/L39Gb/1/) what you need?

Added: `hAxis: {viewWindow: {min: 0.5, max: 2.5}}` to `options` object.

Full list of options is available [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options).